# How can I apply replace to each element of a string? in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to know how I can do to replace exactly every element of a string with another.

Use replace as is proper, but if I send a complete line of a certain character, only the first one replaces me.

example:

```js
let e = "________1", y;

y = e.replace("_","0");

console.log(y);
```

Comment: Use a regex with the *global* flag

Comment: [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a **[regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)** in the "find" argument so that you can specify the "Global Find & Replace" flag (`g`). (Scroll down to the "Advanced searching with flags" section of the link I included to read about `g`.)

```js
let e = "________1", y;

y = e.replace(/_/g,"0"); // Regular expression is delimited by / and /

console.log(y);
```

Comment: I think they want to do it the other way. Have multiple `0`s instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex and the global (`g`) flag:

```js
const pattern = /_/g;
const e = '________1';
const y = e.replace(pattern, '0');

console.log(y);
```